# Docker Swarm Node Ip Address as environment variable

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I'm using docker swarm with multiple manager and worker nodes. I'm starting an application with some env variables from manager nodes. One of them, container host ip address which is running on.

I found template fields.
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/#create-services-using-templates

I can set **HOST={{.Node.Hostname}}** environment variable and it returns host name but i want to use host ip address.
I tried **HOST={{.Status.Addr}}** but an error occured.

```
rpc error: code = InvalidArgument desc = expanding env failed: expanding env "HOST={{.Status.Addr}}": template: expansion:1:9: executing "expansion" at <.Status.Addr>: can't evaluate field Status in type *template.Context
```

How can i use host ip address or inject host ip address as env variable, please help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Why you want IP Address instead of name?

Comment: Because i want to access container's some endpoints outside of docker cluster without any dns,hostname,etc. If i know container's running host ip, i have to access directly it.

Comment: Those are the teamplate variables you can use: https://forums.docker.com/t/example-usage-of-docker-swarm-template-placeholders/73859. There is no template variable for the node ip.